# How to reason that there is no Hamiltonian Circuit?

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

I use my intuition to determine it.
There can't be one at $A$ or $D$ since they have degrees $2$ and if we chose $A$ as starting point, we can at most only go to $D$ once from $E$ or $B$, else we will form a circuit $ABDE$.

Then for the other points I just couldn't find ways to find a cicruit because I always had to enter to either $A$ or $B$ which meant I couldn't exit to enter the other vertex.

Is there a nice logical way to prove this?

Comment: Circuit or path?  If it's a circuit, once you go through vertex $G$ or $F$, you have an extra edge to visit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there is a Hamiltonian cycle. Then it passes through $A$ and $D$. Since those vertices are of degree 2 the edges $BA,AE,ED,DB$ must be in the cycle. But these four edges already form a cycle and this cycle does not go through all seven vertices. Thus there is no Hamiltonian cycle.

More formally, removing the two vertices $B$ and $E$ leaves a graph with three connected components, so there is no Hamiltonian cycle for the original graph.

Comment: Thanks. What does the connected-ness thing have to do with it?  
Is there a theorem or something that talks about if the subgraph is "something" then the original graph is not Hamiltonian?

Comment: @ActuarialStudent101 This is a theorem. If I can find $n$ vertices in a graph, such that their removal yields a graph with more than $n$ connected components, then the original graph has no Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: Is there a name for it so that I can do some reading on it? Thank you

Comment: @ActuarialStudent101 My graph theory textbook has no name for this. It is really the contrapositive of a related theorem that can be proved simply.

Comment: Ah so the Theorem is something like:  
Let $G$ be a connected graph (does it have to be simple?) with $k$ vertices. There does not exist $n\leq k$ so that when removing these $n$ vertices, it splits up the graph into more than $k$ components?

Comment: @ActuarialStudent101 Something like that; you typo'd and replaced "Hamiltonian" with "connected" in the first sentence. Hamiltonicity implies connectedness.